# how to delete all files having specific extention from MY Computer by java

Tags: java

HI I want to write a java program by which I can delete all the files of my computer having a specific extension or character pattern in name.I also want to apply wild card character on the name of file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wish you all the best luck with that, but honestly this does not sound like a question.

Comment: Be careful when testing this program. Better have it do `System.out.println(file)` instead of `file.delete()` until you are really sure it works...

Comment: You might want to look at this class http://download.java.net/jdk7/docs/api/java/nio/file/PathMatcher.htmland its use in this tutorial  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/find.html on how to find files.

Comment: format c: should do well enough.

Comment: actually We have our own products due to those products there create many logs and tmp files in my computer in different place and also due to some other applications, which when become in a very large amount they create trouble and some time disk space not enough or some time system hang , so our testing dept. said to create a java program to delete files from my computer on the basis of wild card character functionality

Comment: Perhaps it would be a better idea to make sure the products all output the temp files and log files to a common location, and delete outdated log data / temp files on a regular basis. Or perhaps they should actually use the Windows Temp folder =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For your program to be really useful you need to do some more thinking, but for a starter;

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

private static void walkDir(final File dir, final Pattern pattern) {
  final File[] files = dir.listFiles();
  if (files != null) {
    for (final File file : files) {
      if (file.isDirectory()) {
        walkDir(file, pattern);
      } else if (pattern.matcher(file.getName()).matches()) {
        System.out.println("file to delete: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
      }
    }
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  walkDir(new File("/home/user/something"), Pattern.compile(".*\\.mp3"));
}
```

Comment: it's working perfect , I can Do my work which I required from it Thanks @ZeroPage

Answer (score 1):

Sidenote (not an answer, but you didn't ask something): Be aware of recursion.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void deleteFilesWithExtension(final String directoryName, final String extension) {

    final File dir = new File(directoryName);
    final String[] allFiles = dir.list();
    for (final String file : allFiles) {
        if (file.endsWith(extension)) {
            new File(aDirectoryName + "/" + file).delete();
        }
    }
}
```